# Angular - Access ng-model input from another controller

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following input with the ng-model on a controller called `main`:

```
<input ng-model="main.oToAdd" type="text" />
```

I then have a `ng-view` using another controller - say `homeController`.

Is is possible to get text from that input field in `homeController`?

I've tried `$scope.oToAdd` and `$scope.$parent.oToAdd` but get `undefined` in both cases?

Thanks

Comment: I got it - It was `$scope.main.oToAdd`

Comment: that doesn't solve the case of sharing your datas between controllers

Comment: I can access the variables from the `home` controller - thats all what I wanted. I guess i should i made clear just want the values don't need to update on `main` controller.
Is this what you mean?

Comment: i thought your question was accessing values of main controller from homecontroller

Comment: are you saying your $scope.main.oToAdd which is in mainController is being accessed without service or factory in homeController?

Comment: $scope.main.oToAdd is in the `homeController`. I can access 'oToAdd` which is on the main controller using what i have above.

Comment: if you have your problem solved, cheers for you :). But your question is misleading